# Dependency Injection in child class

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I am writing a console app in .Net core.  I want to use dependency injection.  My architecture is like this.  Program contains a TradeProcessor (which does all the work) which in turn makes some CompoundTrades.  I have got DI passing some classes into the TradeProcessor via its constructor and that whole ServiceProvider setup.  That works fine.

Now, if i want to DI some classes into the CompoundTrade does the TradeProcessor have to pass them in via the constructor?  I was under the impression that if you register the class to be constructed, all the classes you want to pass in, then they all got passed in "under the hood".  You call CompoundTrade () but the other constructor gets called.  Am i confusing that with DI in Asp.Net?  What is the best design pattern for doing this?  Stick all the ServiceProviders in a static class?

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be resolving anything explicitly. You should put the services you want in the constructor and it will be injected by the DI container. If you need to instantiate child items that are not services then you should look at DI factories for the framework you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You call CompoundTrade() but the other constructor gets called.

That's not how dependency injection works. If you call a constructor explicitly, you get *exactly* that constructor.

You will need to reference you container and tell *your container* to create an instance of that class for you.

If you have an instance that needs to dynamically create new objects that are registered in the container, you will need to pass in the *container* and then use that to create those new objects. Don't call a constructor directly.

```
public TradeProcessor(IServiceProvider provider)
{
   // save the provider in a field
}

public void ThisNeedsADynamicallyCreatedContainerObject()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        var instance = this.provider.GetService<ICompoundTrade>();
    }
    else
    {
        var instance = this.provider.GetService<ISingleTrade>();
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: actual syntax may vary depending on the dependency injection provider you use.*

Comment: Thanks.  Thought that might be the case.